# How to store important queries in Djando models itself?

Tags: django, django-models

there are couple of queries which are important and used several times in different part of application. I wounder it would be great to have a method in the Model itself to retrieve requested data as needed. tried Classmethod and instance method but as the Manager is called in the query I got below error:

`AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via ... instances`

code is look like below:

```
class XDL(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    Order_Code_Description = models.CharField(max_length = 355)
    Status = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    Supplier = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    @classmethod
    def get_count_xdls(cls):
        return cls.objects.all() #query example

    def get_all_supps(self):
        return self.objects.all() #query example
```

explained in Django documentation below:

```
Managers are accessible only via model classes, rather than from model instances, to enforce a separation between “table-level” operations and “record-level” operations
```

**Is there a best practice to store important queries in a method somewhere in Model** (or other parts)? as these queries run several time and also writing it as a method help the documentation as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A customer manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) is a powerful tool for code factorization and labeling complex query.

```
class XDLManager(models.Manager):
    pass

class XDLQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def supplied_by_foo(self):
        return self.filter(supplier='Foo')

class XDL(models.Model):
    objects = XDLManager.from_queryset(XDLQuerySet)()
```

Any methods defined in XDLManager will only be accessible behind `XDL.objects`, methods defined in XDLQueryset will be accesible both behind `XDL.objects` and any function that returns a queryset (`XDL.objects.all()` for instance).

`XDL.objects.filter(supplier='Foo')` and `XDL.objects.supplied_by_foo()` are equivalent

Comment: if you don't want to overwrite `objects` Manager, recommended to  ```objects = models.Manager()
    custom_manager = XDLManager.from_queryset(XDLQuerySet)()``` this way the default manager remains un-touched which is a better practice.